# https and code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, https, cdn

I'm having problems to load

https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js (httpS)

but there are no problems to download

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js (http)

The result is: it doesn't load, the firebug says 
https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js `Status Aborted`

If I use http (not https), then it looks ok: `200 OK`.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Don't they allow to use httpS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries hosted on [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/) are delivered by a CDN that doesn't support https://, and that's why you're getting the errors.

If you really want jQuery (mobile) to be delivered through https:// , you can make use of the [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) or [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDN.ashx#jQuery_Mobile_Releases_on_the_CDN_3) CDN. Sadly, Google doesn't host the jQuery Mobile libraries, and Microsoft doesn't host the 1.3.0 RC version.

The latest release from jQuery mobile hosted at the Microsoft SDN (which can be accessed through https) is [1.2.0](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDNjQueryMobile120.ashx):

> https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.min.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/ajax-loader.gif
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/ajax-loader.png
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-18-black.png
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-18-white.png
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-36-black.png
>   https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-36-white.png